# Django: Compare datetime fields in a template

Tags: django-templates

I have 2 DateTimeFields in my model. One is 'created_at' and other is 'updated_at'. If no updates were made to a specific entry, they are identical.
In my template, I want to show only 'created_at' if they are identical and show both if they are not. Sadly, it's not working.

**My problematic template code:**

```
        <div> Listing date: {{ listing.created_at }}</div>
        {% if listing.created_at != listing.updated_at %}
            <div>Updated: {{ listing.updated_at }}</div>
        {% endif %}
```

**Rendered example:**
Listing date: Jan. 18, 2024, 4:50 a.m.
Updated: Jan. 18, 2024, 4:50 a.m.

In this example, I would like it to only show 'Listing date: Jan. 18, 2024, 4:50 a.m.'

Comment: Just remembered that I have this question unanswered. It was a type problem. If I remember correctly, I had to convert one of them to a string.